# creating a line of worst fit

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

How can I add a line of worst fit on microsoft excel? I've got an exponential graph which has a trendline (line of best fit) but I also need to add a worst fit. I'm aware there's no button like the trendling for that, so what are the steps to create the lowf?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question right, but... Take any line. If the number of points is finite, you can *always* get a worse fit by shifting the line towards infinity (away from the points). There's no end to this, so the worst fit doesn't exist.

Comment: what is a line of 'worst fit' ?

Comment: There are a multitude of videos on youtube that may help. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=line+of+worst+fit+excel

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your problem?